# How to enable adb in frp locked phone?

Tags: boot, frp

By editing boot.img-ramdisk with ro.secure=0 ro.debuggable=1 persist.sys.usb.config=mtp,adb, packing again with mkbootimg produces boot.img.
Heimdall is used with partition information table, and flashed for sboot.bin(bootloader) and boot.img(BOOT).  I conjectured that adb devices would produce connected device.  But experiment shows **NO device connected**.  *I turned off the developer option before going into download mode to mimic situation of locked frp*.

Hypothesis is that flashing with adb enabled boot.img would enable adb debugging after flashing.  What is wrong with this hypothesis?

Comment: are you sure it is booting at all? how did you sign boot.img?